# Loop through parent elements and if child element doesnt exist display text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to loop through all parent classes (.grid) and if it doesnt have a child div with class (.image-container) then display (.content-container) within the same (.grid) section.

**HTML:**

```
<style>
.grid .content-container {
    display:none;
}
</style>

<div class="grid">
    <div class="art">
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="image url" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="title">Title Text</div>
        <div class="content-container">Some Content Goes here</div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
    <div class="art"></div>
        <div class="title">Title Text</div>
        <div class="content-container">Some Content Goes here</div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
    <div class="art">
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="image url" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="title">Title Text</div>
        <div class="content-container">Some Content Goes here</div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
    <div class="art">
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="image url" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="title">Title Text</div>
        <div class="content-container">Some Content Goes here</div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
    <div class="art"></div>
        <div class="title">Title Text</div>
        <div class="content-container">Some Content Goes here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$('.grid').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('.image-container').length == 0) {
        // no children
        $(this).find('.content-container').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, one call:

```
$('.grid')
    .filter(function fi(){return !$('.image-container', this).length})
    .children('.content-container')
    .show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E8CfL/

Or:

```
$('.grid')
    .filter(':not(:has(.image-container))')
    .children('.content-container')
    .show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E8CfL/1

Or:

```
$('.grid:not(:has(.image-container)) .content-container').show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E8CfL/3

Not sure which would be the most efficient, but I have a hunch the first would be.