# ProcessingJS - Rotating the camera in a circe around a fixed point?

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

Recently, I have been trying to build a kind of sailing simulator in Processing, and have encountered a problem. I'm not going to go into details on the project itself because I don't think it's really relevant.

Here's my problem: I need to find a way for the camera to look around while still focusing on the object in the middle (the boat). By this I mean that I'd like to find a circular path for the camera, while it orbits the boat. This is used in many simulators and video games, so I thought it could work in my project.

I have already thought about rotating every object instead of the camera, but I would prefer not to do that because dealing with the boat, sail, and wind is already going to cause lots of rotation and it would just complicate things to rotate it all again every time the player drags the mouse to pivot the point that they are looking from. So, I think finding this path for the camera is my only option right now and I have no idea how to even start to do the math out (going into 9th grade).

If anyone reading this has encountered this problem before, (using the mouse to rotate the camera around an object) please try to give me some tips. Thanks!

Code:

```
float x,y,z,ry;
int trimmingLimit;
void setup()
{
  size(800, 600, P3D); 
  x = width/2;
  y = height/2;
  z = 0;
  ry = 10;
  trimmingLimit = int(random(75,84)); //randomizing sheet length length

}

void draw()
{
  background(#FF844B);
  stroke(255);
  translate(x,y,z);
  pushMatrix();
  rotateY(radians(ry)); //mainsheet trimming and easing
  triangle(-120, 50, 0, -140, 0, 50); //sail
  ry=mouseY/(height/trimmingLimit); //since 80 to 85^o is the maximum amount 
  //the sail can be drawn, the height of the window is adjustable 
  //and divided by 90.
  popMatrix();
  noStroke();
  pushMatrix();
  translate(0,500,0);
  fill(98,122,255,50);
  cylinder(1000,500,15);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  popMatrix();
  fill(#AD8B7C);
  stroke(255);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(0,75);
  rotateX(radians(0));
  translate(0,75);
  triangle(-180,100,0,-50,180,100);
  popMatrix();
  fill(100);
}

float d(float n) //converting to the correct type of degrees (with 0 being wind)
{
  return n-90;
}
```

Comment: Well you didn't do anything wrong, I just took your advice and feedback badly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Haha, ok. Thanks again and sorry.

Comment: The benefit of a having a fiddle (or something like it) is that lots of us that could answer are more fiddlers; we may not know what the answer is, or how to verbalize it, but will play with an example to see what we can do. This is why one is often asked for (although on highly specialized questions like this, it's not quite as useful). It's a sneaky way of engaging a larger group. `;)`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to both this and Processing. What's a fiddle?

Comment: Do a Google search for `jsfiddle.net processing.js` and you should see several examples. Here's one: http://jsfiddle.net/n2yUg/ It's basically a way of making a demo that can be altered and "fiddled" with. Nowadays there are several, like plunkr (specific to angular.js/frameworks), codepen and jsbin. There may be one specifically for processing.js.

Comment: Oh ok. So a fiddler is someone that uses that to alter projects to try to get a better result?

Comment: [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071441/loop-through-parent-elements-and-if-child-element-doesnt-exist-display-text/25071617#25071617). You can do Update or Fork, and have public/private fiddles if you create an account. I use it for all kinds of stuff, including running tests for my own edification. There are also server equivalents like http://codepad.org (those have limited capabilities of course for security reasons).

Comment: I have to go for a while, but again thank you for your help and I will definitely try it out.

Comment: @JaredFarrish (pjs dev here) that's actually a really bad example as it uses the native JS API instead of regular Processing syntax, and uses processing.js 1.0.0 which is years out of date =) A better example would be http://jsbin.com/ratafaqe/1/edit